# Get typescript function return type as object

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator, return-type

I'm actually working on some abstraction with method decorators. For that I actually would like to get the return type of the function as an object that would describe it. Unfortunately, I did not found any solution on that.

Here is a sample of code

```
return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const routeArguments = handleFunctionMetadata(target, propertyKey, descriptor);

    const route = {
        path: path,
        method: 'GET',
        fn: descriptor.value.bind(this),
        arguments: routeArguments
    }

    // I would like to get the return type of descriptor.value here

    if (!target.paths) {
        target.paths = {}
    }

    let key = _.findKey(target.paths, (v) => v === `${route.path}`);

    const docPath = `/${route.path}`;

    const __swaggerRoute = {
        'get': {
            consumes: ["application/json"],
            produces: ["application/json"],
            "summary": "",
            "description": "",
        }
    }

    if (!key) {
        target.paths[docPath] = __swaggerRoute
    } else {
        target.paths[docPath] = _.merge(
            target.paths[docPath],
            __swaggerRoute
        )
    }

    if (!target.routes)
        target.routes = [route];
    else if (_.isArray(target.routes))
        target.routes.push(route)
    return descriptor;
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mMR3zW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.